# Question about relative complement sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove

"X ⊆ Y    if and only if     Y \ (Y \ X) = X"

(<=)

let x be in X and since "Y \ (Y \ X) = X" that implies that x is in Y and x is not in (Y/X). But we as have already derived x is in Y, so X ⊆ Y.

(=>)

Y \ (Y \ X) ⊆ X: 
let y be in Y \ (Y \ X) => y is in Y and y is not in (Y/X). If X is a subset of Y, and (Y/X) is everything that is unique to Y and not in X, then it must be that y is in X.

X ⊆ Y \ (Y \ X): 
let y be in X, and by assumption X ⊆ Y, => y is in Y. If y is in X, then I can say that y is not in (Y/X). Since I have that y is in Y and y is not in (Y/X), then by def of relative component, it must be that X ⊆ Y \ (Y \ X).

We have shown => and <=, so we are done.

Are these conclusions good enough to suffice for a formal proof? I keep feeling like my justifications aren't airtight...

Comment: All seems correct.

Comment: ...but could be made more succinct. Why bother telling us that $x$ is not in $Y \setminus X$ in line 1? Why use the $\implies$ sign (incorrectly) in your final paragraph? Also, take care to make it $Y \setminus X$ not $Y/X$, which is something else entirely. Please forgive my nitpicking, your answer is still good!

Comment: oh i was just trying to apply definitions for practice, as for the ⟹ I thought that just meant a transition from an assumption to a conclusion like, x + 1 = 2 ⟹ x = 1.

Answer (score 1):

$Y - (Y - X) = Y \cap (Y \cap X^c)^c = Y \cap (Y^c \cup X) = Y \cap X$
Since X subset Y iff Y $\cap$ X = X, proof is immediate,